# Python Equivalent Of SCAR

Tags: python, macros

I currently use a small program named 'SCAR' to build up small macro's when I have repetive tasks and I'm feeling lazy. 'SCAR' is designed to find colors on a screen in order to perform tasks. The problem with it is I find its Delfi/Pascal composite language irritating to use, so I was hoping there might be a python equivalent. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at this:

http://code.google.com/p/swapy/

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at https://github.com/WarPie/MacPy
It's a colorbased (windows only) scriptable macro that uses Python 2.7. There is no gui, but it's pretty simple, yet very functinal, just take a look at the "test.py" example, try to run it...

It's not documented, but every function you may need is in the file -> MacPy/Inc/MacPy.py

Comment: I am working on another project which is more similar to SCAR, you can find it at https://github.com/WarPie/Rafiki ... It's still pre-alpha, and might just need some tweaks to get it working properly. Might also need to compile a C-file or two.
I'll try to get a pre-compiled version uploaded some time soon.